# How to add a common colorbar to subplots in Matplotlib and change their limits together

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colormap

I'm trying to have three pseudocolor subplots side by side, with one colorbar for subplots #1 and #2 and a second colorbar for #3. I'd also like the color limits (clim) to be set so it's the same for the first two (so the first colorbar would reflect the values of both subplots #1 and #2).

Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
import matplotlib as mpl


data1 = np.random.random((10,10))
data2 = 2.*np.random.random((10,10))
data3 = 3.*np.random.random((10,10))


f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)

imgplot1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data1, edgecolors='None')

imgplot2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data2, edgecolors='None')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1)
cax2, kw = mpl.colorbar.make_axes([ax1, ax2])
plt.colorbar(imgplot2, cax=cax2, **kw)
imgplot2.set_clim(0,20)

imgplot3 = ax3.pcolormesh(data3, edgecolors='None')
cax3, kw = mpl.colorbar.make_axes([ax3])
plt.colorbar(imgplot3, cax=cax3, **kw)
```

`imgplot2.set_clim(0,20)` sets subplot #2 (though I have seen a backend-dependent issue where it doesn't always update unless you interact with the plot), but is there a way to link the color limits of two subplots so one colorbar can describe both plots?

update: To clarify, I'm looking for the ability to re-adjust clim after the plots have already been created.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `vmin` and `vmax` in both your calls to `pcolormesh` of the axes where the data should be visualized with a common colorbar.

In your case:

```
opts = {'vmin': 0, 'vmax': 20, 'edgecolors': 'none'}
imgplot1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data1, **opts)
imgplot2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data2, **opts)
```

And then get rid of the call to `imgplot2.set_clim(0,20)`.
Alternatively, you could call `set_clim` on `imgplot1` too, using the same parameters. It would have the same effect.

Continuing on your comment below this answer, you could just as easily replace your single call to `imgplot2.set_clim` with a call to a custom function that updates the `clim` of both axes:

```
def update_clims(vmin, vmax, axes):
    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_clim(vmin, vmax)
```

If you really wanted to, you could rebind the `set_clim` method of the `Axes` class to perform the functionality above, provided you add a list of axes that have shared z-data. But that seems like a lot of work for an otherwise easy to implement function. And since you're calling an update of the `clim` already once on *one* axes, you could just as easily replace it with that call.

Comment: You're describing how to set each colorbar limit independently. I'm wondering if there's a way to link the two color limits for the two plots together, or if you have to manually adjust the color limits for both every time you change one.

Comment: @user1704042 a sort of `sharez` option similar to `sharex`, you mean? I didn't get that from your question. To my knowledge, that doesn't exist (yet). Writing an event handler to update the `clim` of the shared axes would be an approach to it, but why not just replace your single call to `imgplot2.set_clim` with a call to a function that does the same? The end-result is the same, no matter if it's implemented in core mpl-functionality or in end-user code. I hope it helps, people often overlook the easy solutions to a problem.